# Auto Line Break in 'align*' Environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to have a line break in some long latex math equations (in the `align` environment). I want to do it automatically, which means I don't want to manually input the `\\`s at the places I want a line break.

I know a possible solution may involve the `breqn` package, but the `dmath*` environment doesn't fit with `align*`.

I want the following code to work.

```latex
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= c_1n + c_2\left(n-1\right) + c_4\left(n-1\right) + c_5\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2} - 1\right) + c_6\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right) + c_7\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right) + c_8\left(n-1\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{c_5}{2} + \frac{c_6}{2} + \frac{c_7}{2}\right)n^2 + \left(c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + \frac{c_5}{2} - \frac{c_6}{2} - \frac{c_7}{2} + c_8\right)n - \left(c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8\right) \numberthis
\end{align*}
```

EDIT: The code alone might not be clear, so here is the whole MWE (using the `mtpro2lite` font):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= c_1n + c_2\left(n-1\right) + c_4\left(n-1\right) + c_5\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2} - 1\right) + c_6\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right) + c_7\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right) + c_8\left(n-1\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{c_5}{2} + \frac{c_6}{2} + \frac{c_7}{2}\right)n^2 + \left(c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + \frac{c_5}{2} - \frac{c_6}{2} - \frac{c_7}{2} + c_8\right)n - \left(c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8\right) \numberthis
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why *automatically*? I'd almost bet that if the automation provides something suitable, it'll end up not being what you want and require manual intervention. It's *far* easier to just insert the linebreak where it's needed. Also, remove the completely unnecessary and superfluous use of `\left`...`\right` where it's not needed (as in `\left(n-1\right)`, for example).

Comment: How or where is the `\numberthis` macro defined?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, the `\numberthis` command is defined as `\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}`.

Comment: If you want to be able to cross-reference these equations, you should replace `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` with `\refstepcounter{equation}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this suits for you? (Note that I didn't use `align` environment)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{showframe}%%Just to draw the frame upto text width
\begin{document}


\begin{dmath}
T(n) = c_1n + c_2\left(n-1\right) + c_4\left(n-1\right) + c_5\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2} - 1\right) + c_6\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right)
 + c_7\left(\frac{n \left(n-1\right)}{2}\right) + c_8\left(n-1\right) = \left(\frac{c_5}{2} + \frac{c_6}{2} + \frac{c_7}{2}\right)n^2 + \left(c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + \frac{c_5}{2} - \frac{c_6}{2} - \frac{c_7}{2} + c_8\right)
  n - \left(c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8\right) 
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it suits me well.

Comment: Thanks, if this suggestion meets your requirement, then please acknowledge by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could stick the material to the right of `&=` into a suitably constructed `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{\raggedright$\displaystyle #1 $}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
T(n) 
&= \mybox{c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5\Bigl(\frac{n (n-1)}{2} - 1\Bigr) \linebreak + c_6\Bigl(\frac{n (n-1)}{2}\Bigr) + c_7\Bigl(\frac{n (n-1)}{2}\Bigr) + c_8(n-1)} \\[2\jot]
&= \mybox{\Bigl(\frac{c_5}{2} + \frac{c_6}{2} + \frac{c_7}{2}\Bigr)n^2 + \Bigl(c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + \frac{c_5}{2} - \frac{c_6}{2} - \frac{c_7}{2} + c_8\Bigr) n \linebreak - (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)^{\mathstrut}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if you add a label, the label appears at the top of the line, how can I move it down? Also, a solution that makes the above automatic will be great. :)

Comment: @remmymilkyway — Please clarify what you mean by “label”. An equation number, maybe?

Comment: Yes, by "label" I mean an equation number. @Mico