# Auto Line Break Math Equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

### Preface

First, I would like to say that this question is not the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671436/auto-line-break-in-align-environment). This question has some additional constrainsts.

### The question

I am writing some long equations in my LaTeX document, and I want to have some line breaks in them. *And I want them to be added automatically because I have a lot of equations already*. For example, look at this equation:
[image: Bad equation]
It practically goes out of the page! I would like the effect to be like this:
[image: Good equation]

### Constraints

1. I don't want the `breqn` package to be involved. The package messes around with LaTeX math too much. For example, it makes the equal signs shorter. Plus it is known to have many compatibility issues.
2. The equation number (or "the tag") should be in the bottom line (there can be a line break before it).
3. It must be compatible the the `mtpro2` package.
4. **(This isn't a must.)** All the code should be only added to the preamble. (Because as mentioned before, there are a lot of equations in my document already.)

### MWE

Here is the code that is used to produce the equation in the first picture.

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-1]
    \begin{align}
        \nonumber T(n) &= c_1n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - 1\right) + c_6\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right) + c_7\left(\frac{n (n-1)}{2}\right) + c_8(n-1) \\
        &= \left(\frac{c_5}{2} + \frac{c_6}{2} + \frac{c_7}{2}\right)n^2 + \left(c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + \frac{c_5}{2} - \frac{c_6}{2} - \frac{c_7}{2} + c_8\right)n - (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)\;\text{.}
    \end{align}
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you like a pet unicorn, too? 

Comment: It is unlikely that one can obtain 100% automation as there will always be corner cases where a humans opinion is needed. Additionally there is no consensus on a single rule on how to line break displayed math, though a lot of people tend to follow the recommendations set forth in Mathematics into Type by the AMS.

Comment: breqn doesn't change the font so does not change = sign normally

Comment: it is a duplicate question you can still hope for newer answers there

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I found out that the = sign was changed, I removed the `breqn` package and the sign went back to normal. By the way, thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: you have something strange in your font set up, it may affect any other answer if you show no example. breqn (or don't do it) would be the standard answer here, allowing line breaking is easy enough, allowing that while aligning is very hard and there is no reason to suppose any alternative method is less invasive than breqn, breqn+flexisym is around 2.5K lines of code, any alternative will be a similar amount so rather much to expect as an answer so "don't use breqn" may not be a reasonable constraint for a posting here.